# Check if a ruby Class is in a particular Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module, controller

I have a `controller` object with `controller.class == Admin::TeamsController`.  I might also have a circumstance like `controller.class == Admin::UsersController`.  Now I want to check if this is true:

```
controller.class.to_s.match?('Admin::')
```

I.e., I want to know:  Is this object of a class that's defined within the `Admin` module namespace?  To spell that out, is the structure like the following?

```
module Admin
  module SomeOtherModulePerhaps
    class TeamsController
    end
  end
end
```

My question:  Is there a nicer Ruby way to test for this?  It feels kind of hacky to convert the class to a string, then do a regex match like that.

EDIT:

For my constrained use case, I could check like this:

`controller.class.to_s.split('::').first == 'Admin'`

But that doesn't quite solve the general case that other people might have.  For example, there might be cases like `XyzAdmin::TeamsController` that one might want to exclude, on which my first solution fails, or `Foo::Admin::TeamsController` that one might want to *include*, on which my second solution fails.

I'd like to find a better way.

Answer (score 4):

Rails comes with [`module_parents`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-module_parents):

```
module Admin
  module SomeOtherModulePerhaps
    class TeamsController
    end
  end
end

controller = Admin::SomeOtherModulePerhaps::TeamsController.new

controller.class.module_parents
#=> [Admin::SomeOtherModulePerhaps, Admin, Object]

controller.class.module_parents.include?(Admin)
#=> true
```

Under the hood, it uses [`Module#name`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-name), i.e. `"Admin::SomeOtherModulePerhaps::TeamsController"`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
controller.class.const_defined?(:Admin)
```

returns true or false

Answer (score 1):

What about to use `controller_path`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-c-controller_path

```
controller_path.match?('admin')
```

Comment: In my case I'm modifying the file config/initializers/lograge.rb and have a code block that begins with `config.lograge.custom_payload do |controller| ...` so I have access to the `controller` object but can't invoke the `controller_path` method.

Answer (score 1):

You might try playing with [`Module#nesting`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-c-nesting), but it’d return rather unexpected results depending on whether the class was defined using fully qualified name *or* a set of nesting statements.

After all, class names in ruby *are* simple constants, and one might define the class name in many ways, like:

```rb
module A
  def self.class!
    Class.new do |c|
      define_method :test do puts c.name end
    end
  end
end
A.const_set :C, A.class!
#⇒ A::C
A::C.new.test
#⇒ A::C
```

Which roughly means, there are tons of ways to fool the best detection mechanism. That said, I’d go with the easiest one.

```rb
controller.class.to_s.split('::')[0...-1].include?('Admin')
```

Any occurrence of `Admin` would be counted, save for when `Admin` is the *last* item in the class name chain.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know: Is this object of a class that's defined within the `Admin` module namespace?
>
> [...]
>
> Is there a nicer Ruby way to test for this?

Classes aren't defined in modules, therefore, there is neither a nice way nor any other way to test for it.

When you write a class definition body inside a module definition body, you do not create *any relationship whatsoever* between the module and the class. The only relationship is between the *constant* that the class gets assigned to and the module, not the class.

Therefore, since this relationship does not exist, you cannot test for it.